# Why Pycharm's struggles with Scipy functions that can return multiple outputs?

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm

Scipy is one of the most used scientific packages in Python. Most of its functions have a common interface: they either return only a value (which can be `float/np.ndarray`) or a `tuple`, where the second term is `boolean` or a `dict`. Something like this:

```
value = some_scipy_function(*args, full_output=False)
value, flag = some_scipy_function(*args, full_output=True)
```

Yet, if you use PyCharm, it **constantly** raises warnings for SciPy functions because it does not understand that that these functions will indeed return a single value if `full_output` is `False`.

---

> Why is it so difficult for PyCharm to do this? This information is not only available in the Docstrings for the SciPy functions, but also obvious from the code, before excecution. Additionally, it most often does not allow you to suppress these warnings unlike others, perhaps because they are seen as major warnings (it would be impossible to subtract from a tuple).

Frustration aside, I feel that it is a bit odd that if you use Python's most used scientific computing library, your file is filled with unsuppressable warnings because of this. Am I the only one who has been frustrated by this?

---

## Examples

- `logsumexp` (or generally most linear algebra functions)
- `brentq` (or generally most optimization functions)

```
from scipy.special import logsumexp

logw = np.log(np.random.rand(1000))
lse_plus_value = 1.0 + exp(logsumexp(logw, return_sign=False))  # raises a warning
```

Comment: Please provide *working* code that lets us reproduce the issue you're having.

Comment: @matszwecja Added an example!

Comment: @Euler_Salter "raises a warning" is a bit non-specific: can you tell us what the warning is and how it is raised in detail?

Comment: You cannot add a float to a tuple (or a vector in case of optimization). The point is that it expects the output to always be a tuple, even if you specify `full_output=False` (or equivalent argument)

Comment: I understand that, but I would really want to see the actual verbatim error and how it shows up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no way that PyCharm could infer the return type to be variable, since SciPy doesn't ship with type stubs (and PyCharm doesn't ship them internally either) that would define the override that's [(for `logsumexp`, as an example) only documented via the docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.12.0/reference/reference/generated/scipy.special.logsumexp.html#scipy.special.logsumexp)

> Returns
>
> res : ndarray
> The result, `np.log(np.sum(np.exp(a)))` calculated in a numerically
> more stable way. If `b` is given then `np.log(np.sum(b*np.exp(a)))`
> is returned.
>
> sgn : ndarray
> If return_sign is True, this will be an array of floating-point
> numbers matching res and +1, 0, or -1 depending on the sign
> of the result. If False, only one result is returned.

The mechanism for adding such a type annotation would be [@typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/typing.html#overload); something like

```
@overload
def logsumexp(..., return_sign=True) -> tuple[ndarray, bool]:

@overload
def logsumexp(..., return_sign=False) -> ndarray:
```

For what it's worth, I don't see an "unsuppressable warning" for

```
from scipy.special import logsumexp

a, b = logsumexp([1, 2, 3, 4], b=[4, 3, 2, 1], return_sign=True)
```

in my PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Professional Edition).
You can of course try to clue your PyCharm in more by adding e.g. a type annotation after such a line:

```
b: bool
```

or even a `typing.cast`:

```
a, b = cast(tuple[ndarray, bool], logsumexp(...))
```